# Is there a way to create key-value paired dict from panda dataframe using index and column name as key?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, type-conversion

I want to convert pandas dataframe to a key value pair dictionary by combining index and column name as key. Is there a easy way to do it?

Before:

```
             T1      T2  
    apple    5       1   
    pear     2       1.5  
    banana   10      12
```

After:

```
{'apple_T1': 5,
 'apple_T2': 1,
 'pear_T1': 2,
  ...
 'banana_T2':12
 }
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one step:

```
{f"{row}_{k}": v for row, data in df.iterrows() for k, v in data.items()}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I can't believe I've been stuck at it for over an hour.

Comment: In fairness the other answers will work too :) feel free to accept if it solves the problem :)

Comment: small correction, the answer should be `{f"{row}_{k}": v for row, data in df.iterrows() for k, v in data.items()}`

Comment: @Gold79 oops, ta

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) followed by a dictionary comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[5, 1], [2, 1.5], [10, 12]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["T1", "T2"], index=["apple", "pear", "banana"])

result = { f"{kout}_{kin}" : value for kout, d in df.to_dict("index").items() for kin, value in d.items()}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'apple_T1': 5, 'apple_T2': 1.0, 'pear_T1': 2, 'pear_T2': 1.5, 'banana_T1': 10, 'banana_T2': 12.0}
```

Comment: I don't *think* you need the cast to dict: you can just iterate row-wise, as the resulting objects already have a `.items()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.to_dict(orient='index')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Set your dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["T1", "T2"], 
    data=[[5,1], [2, 1.5], [10, 12]], 
    index=["apple", "pear", "banana"]
)
```

Apply `.to_dict` method:

```
d = df.to_dict(orient='index')
result = {f"{k1}_{k2}": v for k1 in d for k2, v in d[k1].items()}
```

Result:

```
{'apple_T1': 5,
 'apple_T2': 1,
 'banana_T1': 10,
 'banana_T2': 12,
 'pear_T1': 2,
 'pear_T2': 1.5}
```

Answer (score 1):

A direct way is to loop through all index and columns, and define the dictionary items one by one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 1], [2, 1.5], [10, 12]], 
                  columns=['T1', 'T2'], 
                  index=['apple', 'pear', 'banana'])
new_dict = {}
for i in df.index:
    for j in df.columns:
        new_dict[i + '_' + j] = df.loc[i, j]
print(new_dict)
```

Output is

```
{'apple_T1': 5,
 'apple_T2': 1.0,
 'pear_T1': 2,
 'pear_T2': 1.5,
 'banana_T1': 10,
 'banana_T2': 12.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.iterrows()` but you need be careful to get what you want:

```
>>> {f'{row}_{k}':v for row, col in df.iterrows() for k,v in list(col.items())[1:]}

{'apple_T1': 5,
 'apple_T2': 1.0,
 'pear_T1': 2,
 'pear_T2': 1.5,
 'banana_T1': 10,
 'banana_T2': 12.0}
```